# registering global variables with javascript within a loop

Tags: javascript, php, global-variables

In php you can add to the global variables quite easily by simply doing:

```
$array = ['pigs','cows'];
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); ++$i ){
    $GLOBALS[$array[i]] = 'somthing cool';
}
```

I am trying to achieve something similar with js but not sure if is possible:

```
var events = [
    'AboutView',
    'FindView',
];
for( var i = 0 ; i < views.length ; ++i ){
    /* where <views[i]> is a globally defined variable the name of the array val */
    <views[i]> = require( 'ui/common_new/' + views[i] );
    Ti.include( 'events/'+views[i]+'.js' );
}
```

To then be able to access the view like this:

```
var new FindView = new FindView();
```

Comment: You cant define global PHP Variables with JS if you want to do that ... if you want to define a global variable in JS, you can attach it to the global window object. If you dont use strict mode, you can just use it without declaration, it will be automatically declared as global. You could of course try to use a POST to send a global variable to the next PHP script ... this mgiht work. But its senseless imho.

Comment: sorry i was only using php to illustrate what i was trying to achieve in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your views array outside of your loop, and then append each item to it. Like this:

```
var views = [];

for( var i = 0 ; i < views.length ; ++i ){
    /* where <views[i]> is a globally defined variable the name of the array val */
    views[i] = require( 'ui/common_new/' + views[i] );
    Ti.include( 'events/'+views[i]+'.js' );
}
```

or do window.variable to define a global variable from any scope

Comment: Hey sorry i should have taken my explanation one step further.. see edited post

Comment: perfect! for browsers i can use window thanks, i had forgotten about that!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic function that will create the views inside a specified container:

```
function registerViews(views, container)
{
    views.forEach(function(view) {
        container[view] = require('ui/common_new/' + view);
        Ti.include('events/' + view + '.js');
    });
}

var views = [
    'AboutView',
    'FindView',
];
```

And then call it with `window` if you want:

```
registerViews(views, window);

var x = new FindView();
```

Or another container:

```
var test = {};

registerViews(views, test);

var x = new test.FindView();
```